# java list of objects comparison

Tags: java, comparator, compareto

I am having `List<Student> stud1 = new ArrayList<Student>();`
and `List<Student> stud2 = new ArrayList<Student>();`

And `Student` class is having members like **name**, **address**.

What i have to do is , I have to list the Student from stud1 (if **stud1's Student name** is equal to **stud2's Student name**).

How to achieve this ?

I want to know, is there any existing **java libraries** like **ListUtil** to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are many ways to compare elements inside a Collection if you only need to compare the name of the students you can iterate and compare names in both lists, but i think is more elegant to implement Comparable and create your compare_to method in your Student class.

More info here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate through both of them and check and keep adding in a resultant list
If you want to optimize it then

Create a map

```
Map<String, List<Student>> dictionaryMapOfStudents;
```

and then select `HashMap` implementation and look for only those students whose name matches somehow,

For example

```
A Asdahd, Aasldfalf, Aero
B Baksd, Bajsr, Biro
```

So now you wont search full list, narrowed down search

Answer (score 3):

This example may be helps you

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Repeated {
public static void main( String  [] args ) {
    Collection listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("milan","dingo", "elpha", "hafil", "meat", "iga", "neeta.peeta"));
    Collection listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("hafil", "iga", "binga", "mike", "dingo"));

    listOne.retainAll( listTwo );
    System.out.println( listOne );
}
```

}

Comment: Only think you have to consider while doing this is you should have `equals()` overridden for Students to compare objects based on fields such as first name, last name, etc..

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

1. Contruct a `HashSet<String>` containing all the names of `Student`s in `stud2`
2. For each `Student` in `stud1`, check if his name is in the set and if it is, add it to the list to return.

Answer (score 0):

Here some algorithm for you:

- Create Array List for stud3
- Loop based on stud1 from int i = 0 to i = (stud1.size() - 1)

  - Loop based on stud2 from int j = 0 to j = (stud2.size() - 1)

    - Check if stud1.get(i).getName() equals to stud2.get(j).getName()

      - Check if stud1.get(i) already on stud3

        - continue
      - Else

        - Add stud1.get(i) to stud3

Comment: step 5: after printing name break "for j" loop, or you can print same name few times if stud2 contains it more than once

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks for the pointer, I'm using continue when check if there is already the name in the third array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet for lookup name matching:

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Student(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> s1 = new ArrayList<Student>();
        List<Student> s2 = new ArrayList<Student>();

        // generate data
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Student s = new Student("Student" + i, "");
            s1.add(s);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Student s = new Student("Student" + i, "");
            s2.add(s);
        }

        // create a lookup HashSet
        Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Student s : s2) {
            nameSet.add(s.getName());
        }

        List<Student> result = new ArrayList<Student>();
        // perform lookup
        for (Student s : s1) {
            if (nameSet.contains(s.getName())) {
                // add the matching student to the result list
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```